# Bootstrap wysiwyg toolbar popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

I'm trying to implement a wysiwyg editor with a toolbar popover (Formatting Options popover, like in Gmail). Everything works except the buttons in popover.

I'm calling this `$('#editor').wysiwyg()` also once the popover is shown. Is it the right way?

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: Is this a plugin? Never mind, I found it.[http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) Show some code or a jsfiddle